# AWS Service Control Policie to prevend opening Internet Connections in a VPN Environment

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-vpc, aws-organizations

we have multiple aws sub accounts which are under a billing account (organization). since those accounts are connected via vpn to our private cloud i want prevent that developers can open ports to the internet by default. is there a good default policy to prevent most basic stuff which can cause security problems without limiting the developers to much? basically the should be allow to start and stop stuff inside but we should make sure that they can't open stuff which could cause security problems to our privat cloud. i just went quick over some settings and came up with this policy, but i would like to hear if there is more to consider or if there are already good examples.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "*",
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": [
                "aws-portal:ModifyAccount",
                "aws-portal:ModifyBilling",
                "aws-portal:ModifyPaymentMethods"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": [
                "budgets:ModifyBudget"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": [
                "directconnect:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": [
                "cur:DeleteReportDefinition"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": [
                "organizations:CreateAccount",
                "organizations:CreateOrganization",
                "organizations:CreateOrganizationalUnit",
                "organizations:DeleteOrganization",
                "organizations:DeleteOrganizationalUnit",
                "organizations:DeletePolicy",
                "organizations:DisablePolicyType",
                "organizations:InviteAccountToOrganization",
                "organizations:LeaveOrganization",
                "organizations:MoveAccount",
                "organizations:RemoveAccountFromOrganization",
                "organizations:UpdateOrganizationalUnit",
                "organizations:UpdatePolicy"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:AttachInternetGateway",
                "ec2:CreateInternetGateway",
                "ec2:DeleteInternetGateway",
                "ec2:DetachInternetGateway"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:AttachVpnGateway",
                "ec2:CreateVpnConnection",
                "ec2:CreateVpnConnectionRoute",
                "ec2:CreateVpnGateway",
                "ec2:DeleteVpnConnection",
                "ec2:DeleteVpnConnectionRoute",
                "ec2:DeleteVpnGateway",
                "ec2:DetachVpnGateway"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```